# Proximity sensor to wake up the android device is not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-service, android-sensors

I am trying to wake up my android device using the proximity sensor but it not working when the phone is in sleep..Please any body tell me how to do it.OR Is there any ways to wake up the android device without using the power button?
Here is my code.

```
public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mProximity;


private PowerManager mPowerManager;
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

@Override
public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);





}

@Override
public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

}

@Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float distance = event.values[0];

    System.out.println("DistanceDistance"+distance);


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: it could be because of the doze mode since MM. Also, it depends on device, huawei has an own energy management...and it´s tricky to get around this....

Comment: Which sensors may be alive during sleep mode is largely up to device manufacturers, not app developers.

Comment: Is there is any way i can do that???